Nuxt running on CMS - how to ignore part of the path?
I am deploying an app on a CMS. The path that is requested might look like this:
https://preview-blockstest-chesheast.cloud.contensis.com/roads/potholes
However, my app doesn't know about this path (which could be anything - generated by the CMS) and needs to behave as if the route of the site has been requested.
